# Class not found when using namespace

Tags: php, wordpress, namespaces

I am trying to call a function of another class by including the class with namespace. But when I do so, I get an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'inc\Activate' not found
```

This error does not occur when I include the class with require_once instead of namespace.

I have generated the vendor folder with the help of composer for defining global namespace

This is my code

**aotoload_psr.php**

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'inc\\' => array($baseDir . '/inc'),
);
```

**Activate.php (Class to be included)**

```
namespace inc;

class Activate
{
    public static function activate()
    {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
```

**fahad-plugin.php (Where class is being included)**

```
use inc\Activate;
class FahadPlugin
    {
        function activate()
        {
            Activate::activate();
        }

        $fp = new FahadPlugin();
        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($fp, 'activate'));
    }
```

[File directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYFxi.png)

Any Idea where I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the path to `Activate.php` file exactly? it should be inside the `inc` folder right beside your `vendor` directory ( Or, "`../../../inc/Activate.php`" from the point of view where your `aotoload_psr.php` file is located).

Comment: `Activate.php` is inside the `inc` folder. I have updated the question with the file structure @Top-Master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your autoloader is not working because `WordPress` will never activate it;

Importing it in your `fahad-plugin.php` file should fix it, like below:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @wordpress-plugin
 * Plugin Name: Fahad-plugin
 * Description: Your plugin description
 * Version:     1.0
 * Author:      Fahad Shaikh
 * Author URI:  https://example.com
*/

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use inc\Activate;

class FahadPlugin {
  function activate() {
    Activate::activate();
  }
}

$fp = new FahadPlugin();
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($fp, 'activate'));
```

> **Note:** `WordPress` loads the `bootstrap.php` file if there is no file with the same name as your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As Top-Master said the Location of the Activate.php should be inside the inc folder.
Second problem is you must call the class outside the class. your are calling the FahadPlugin class inside the class itself.